# Oracle NVL with empty string

Tags: sql, oracle, null, nvl

I have this table where NULL is the `NULL` value, not the string NULL:

```
MYCOL
--------
NULL
example
```

Why does this query *not* return the `NULL` row?

```
select * from example_so where nvl(mycol, '') = '';
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`''` is again `NULL` in Oracle, because Oracle doesn't support empty Strings just like Other High Level languages or DBMS..

You need to look for NULL/empty string using `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`

No other relational operator work against `NULL`, though it is syntactically valid. [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/36233)

It has to be,

```
select * from example_so where mycol IS NULL
```

**EDIT:** As per [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements005.htm)

> Oracle Database currently treats a character value with a length
>   of zero as null. However, this may not continue to be true in future
>   releases, and Oracle recommends that you do not treat empty strings
>   the same as nulls.

Comment: How come `''` is `NULL`? Isn’t `''` the empty string?

Comment: Because an empty string is NULL in Oracle. See my demo in the answer.

Comment: Strange, I can’t seem to find this in the documentation.

Comment: I accepted your answer as it answers my question. But note that relational operators *do* work with `NULL`. It is quite touchy though.

Comment: @kmkaplan added some sql to [fiddle link here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/36233).. as demo.. SQL runs successfully, but the result of the expression would be `UNKNOWN` .. the docs I referred here show the same.

Comment: `AND` and `OR` can be used with `NULL` to give useful (that is not `NULL`) results.

Comment: `OR` will suppress any index usage.

Comment: Most hypocritical piece of documentation i've ever seen. Basically saying "You shouldn't treat empty string as `NULL`. But the DB does. But might change in the future. But we don't know when. And you can't control or change the behavior. But don't treat them the same."

Answer (score 9):

Because `NULL = NULL` is simply unknown. A third state perhaps? It is neither `TRUE` nor `FALSE`.

**Oracle considers an EMPTY STRING as NULL.**

`nvl(mycol, '')` makes no real sense, as you are making the NULL back to NULL and comparing it again with NULL.

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 1 val, 'NULL' str FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 2, NULL str FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 3, '' str FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 4, 'some value' str FROM dual)
  6  SELECT val, NVL(str, 'THIS IS NULL') FROM data WHERE str IS NULL
  7  /

       VAL NVL(STR,'THI
---------- ------------
         2 THIS IS NULL
         3 THIS IS NULL

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

select * from example_so where nvl(mycol, '') = '';

**nvl(mycol, '') will be resulted as NULL**
and when you compared NULL with empty string it cant be compared

```
create table t(id varchar2(2));
insert into t values (nvl(null,''));   <------ this will insert NULL
insert into t values (nvl(null,'et'));
```